# google closure not suppressing warnings

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

S:\Source_Control\Test.js:24027: WARNING - Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being used.
/** @suppress {suspiciousCode} */ $['player'].Player;

The suppress tag does not appear to be functioning. Am I using it wrong?

This is the code:

```
/** @suppress {suspiciousCode} */ $['player'].Player;
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppress annotations are only supported at the file level or the function level.

You'll need to place your suppress annotation on the function:

```
/** @suppress{suspiciousCode} */
function() {
    $['player'].Player;
}
```

Comment: Wrapping it in a function made it so I didn't need to use the suppress tag anyway. Thanks.